# Wallet and Blockchain on different hard drives cant communicate

Tags: monerod

At my wits end. In breif my wallet is on C:/ and my lmdb is on D:/. The GUI tells me that it knows its location, D:/lmdb. Indeed that exactly where the program downloaded it to yet still I can not automatically start daemon. Have tried the startup flag
monerod.exe --data-dir D:\desired\path\to\your\blockchain.
The flag box won't accept the space after exe. So my flag looks like,   monerod.exe--data-dir D:\lmdb. Chat GPT suggested using = between dir and D, this didnt work either. Any ideas ??